# Convert this CSV to a qgis usable format

Tags: qgis, polygon, csv

I have been given a CSV (which has been converted from a RDF). I want to convert the CSV file to a usable format so that I can display these polygons in QGIS.

[image: CSV File]

The original file and some other formats are available here, but no format seems to work with QGIS. http://datos.santander.es/dataset/?id=distritos

How can I convert it to a usable format, such as GeoJson?

Comment: I searched for convert csv to json and got http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-geojson.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can import the file using the delimited text file import button, simply chose semicolon `;` as the delimiter and WKT as the geometry type. This leaves you with the simple task of finding out what the projection of the data is. I tried searching the site but my spanish isn't that good.

Comment: That worked properly, I had tried dragging the csv file which didn't work.

Comment: Dragging the csv file to canvas adds it as a geometryless table, useful for joining with exiting layers. If you want the geometry from the file, some more information are necessary, that can be set in the `delimited text` dialogue.